# ConcurrentHashMap in Servlet

Tags: java, concurrency

I have `ConcurrentHashMap` that I store in the servlet context, data in the map changes concurrently, I know that servlet context isn't thread safe but `ConcurrentHashMap` is (for writing). Should I use synchronize construction in this case?

```
 synchronized (context) {
   ConcurrentHashMap messages =(ConcurrentHashMap)context.getAttribute("map");
   String mes  = messages.get("id");  // can be changed by another thread?
   messages.put("id",mes +"changed by thread 1");   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but i don't see the problem. "messages"  is a local variable in this example, every thread would have one. You are not sharing "messages"

The only problem could arise when you read from "context" so, you will only need to sync that read

```
ConcurrentHashMap messages = null;
synchronized (context) {
    ConcurrentHashMap messages =(ConcurrentHashMap)context.getAttribute("map");
}
String mes  = messages.get("id");  // can be changed by another thread?
messages.put("id",mes +"changed by thread 1");
```

but, best thing is to avoid that. How you will avoid sync on read form context? simple, you must not write on context or do that only on the initialitation process.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the Map when the ServletContext inits, then you don't need to synchronize getting it, as you won't remove it until the context is closed.

It doesn't matter that if the Map handles concurrency or not. In the latter case then you would need to synchronize on the Map, but as you are using one that handles concurrency, you don't even need to do that either.

Comment: In moment when I get message and change it, based on it previous value, this previous value can be changed by another thread (watch code)?

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about changes being made on the Map after you holds a reference to it, what you can do is wrap the code by a method that returns a copy of the Map. In that case you will hold a snapshot of the Map from the copy time.

If you want to synchronize changes completely you can use Collections.syncrhonizedMap(...)